# SwiftUI - Controlling media playback of ios app on watchOS App

Tags: swiftui, avaudioplayer, watchos

I have a music streaming iOS app, i'm trying to implement a watchOS app to work with existing ios App.. I can play music on iOS app from watchos without no problem...

My question is how can i access player events such as play,pause, skip, elapsed time etc.. from watchos?

First thought was to use NowPlayingView() directly in my watchOS app, but if another audio is playing on my iphone (like Spotify) my app displays that apps controls...

Comment: Look into Handoff or WatchConnectivity